# 2002 Saab 93 SE Ignition Coil - Fluid found inside, engine rumbling

Tags: ignition-coil, saab

I had a new coil installed 6 months ago in my 2002 Saab 93 SE and it has been running fine until the other day when the engine started rumbling quite violently.

Took it to a garage and after they took the coil out they found a clear, odourless liquid which appears to be leaking *from* the coil. Would assume its "oily" water but they aren't 100%.

Any ideas what it might be, and how or where the liquid came from? My understanding is the coil is covered, the car is in good condition and there aren't any other visible leaks.

Having a new coil installed tomorrow.

This is what the part looks like if that helps.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like someone may have just put dielectric grease on the coils/plugs when they were replaced last. Where exactly was the liquid coming out of the coil?

Comment: Not sure - just dealt with them on the phone so far, but I will ask tomorrow when I go in. That definitely matches the description though so I will accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That part is actually a Direct Ignition Cassette.   It does far more than just act as an ignition coil.   There normally is some white great at the bottom, but it normally isn't leaking.  It is an expensive part but seems to fail in some way normally every 100k or so.